# mongoctl on synology NAS server

Tags: linux, mongodb, mlab, synology

Is it possible to use mongoctl on a NAS server ?
I have a Synology 213j, and I have successfully installed mongoctl but when I run a `mongoctl dump` command I get the error message :

> ERROR: Unable to find a compatible 'mongodump' executable for version
>   2.4.6. You may need to run 'mongoctl install-mongodb 2.4.6' to install it.
>
> Here is your enviroment:
>
> $PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/syno/sbin:/usr/syno/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/bin:/opt/sbin
>
> $MONGO_HOME=None
>
> mongoDBInstallationsDirectory=/root/mongodb (in mongoctl.config)

And when I run `mongoctl install-mongodb 2.4.6` I get :

> Running install for linux 32bit to mongoDBInstallationsDirectory (/root/mongodb)...

and nothing else.

Comment: I think 213j is not intel nor ARM, it is some other processor so I believe not, really mongodb isn't even designed to run on ARM only intel

Answer (score 1):

It could be a bug in mongoctl when you try to install from root. Can you try that from a different user other than root? Also as a workaround for this problem, you can manually download/unzip the desired mongodb version from http://www.mongodb.org/downloads to the mongoDBInstallationsDirectory show above

-abdul

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I have tried with a different user and I have the same problem. I also tried to unzip mongodb to mongoDBInstallationsDirectory but having the same error message.